# Can't install Shoreditch

Tags: shoreditch

I'm on Drupal 7 and Civi 5.9.0. I went and got a copy of the extension straight from GitHub. There is says they recommend using version 5.0+, even though the page on the Civi site says it's compatible with 4.7 only. I uploaded everything, but it's still not available to enable. Is it really only working on 4.7? This is listed as how Spark is setup and we'd like to be able to use that new look for our site as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And just as I posted that, I found the answer on my own - it is not called Shoreditch in the extension listing. It is called "CiviCRM Bootstrap theme". So I'm keeping the question here and adding the answer for anyone who gets stuck like I did looking for the wrong name.